# Link HTML para download vindo do banco

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Estou gravando um endereço no banco e com ajax busco ele para exibição ao usuário. Provisoriamente, estou gravando ele no input abaixo:

```
              <tr>
              <td>Download:</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="anexo" id = "anexo" size="60"></td>
              </tr>
```

O Ajax retorna o valor correto do banco, com o HTTP e tudo:

```
http://pcn-sig.peccin.local/sig/subsistemas/projeto_testes/projetos/BASE/11.docx
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha pergunta é: De que forma poderia fazer isso virar um hiperlink ou botão para download? Testei button, onclick, mas não consegui ele reconhecer o link.
Obrigado

UPDATE

O Ajax que carrega os dados é esse:

```js
       // Verifica se foi concluído com sucesso e a conexão fechada (readyState=4)
        if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {
            // Verifica se o arquivo foi encontrado com sucesso
            if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
                //Se o retorno foi vazio do Oracle
                if (xmlreq.responseText == "") {
                    document.getElementById("projeto").focus();
                    alert("Não existe o projeto informado!");
                    ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = '';
                        document.getElementById("projeto").value = '';
                    });
                //Se encontrou dados
                } else {
                    //Aqui recebe os dados do processa.php, abre e aplica nos campos desejados
                    var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
                    // função para preencher os campos com os dados
                    ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = dados[id];
                    });
                }
            } else {
                result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
            }
        }
```

UPDATE 2

Abaixo consegui abrir uma janela nova ao clicar, mas ao invés de passar a url ele passa o this.value

```
              <td>Download:</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="anexo" id = "anexo" onclick="location.href='this.value';" /></td>
```

Comment: Tentou inserir a url em um `hyperlink` utilizando a tag `<a>`?

Comment: Eu não sei como fazer isso, pois o Ajax alimenta o campo pela id dele, na página o valor aparece corretamente, mas como texto apenas.

Comment: Você está utilizando jQuery ou algum outro framework ou Javascript puro?

Comment: Estou usando JS puro. Tentei a resposta abaixo, mas  deu erro Ajax...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
<td><input type="text" name="anexo" id = "anexo" size = "65" readonly = "true" onclick="location.href=this.value;" /></td>
```

Quando clico no campo já abre a janela para download. 
Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 5):

Em vez de colocar o caminho do arquivo em um id coloque no href e use o atributo download, exemplo:

```js
var arquivoParaDownload = "https://www.novatec.com.br/livros/javascriptguia/capitulo9788575222485.pdf";

$("a").prop('href', arquivoParaDownload); // Para jQuery =< 1.6 use attr()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" download="DownloadMyJavascriptBookt">Download</a>
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que em versões mais recentes do `jQuery` o `attr` foi substituído pelo `prop`. +1

Comment: Tentei, mas o ajax não carrega nenhum dos outros dados e no firebug fica em branco. Obrigado

Comment: @Diego na sua imagem você esta usando um input, utilize uma tag <a>, caso você tenha arquivos que podem ser abertos no navegador, como por exemplo pdf, abra ele em uma nova aba usando target="_blank"

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues tentei usar a tag <a>, mas ela não retorna nada.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você deverá utilizar um [hyperlink](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) tag `<a>` e utilizando JavaScript você irá adicionar a URL no atributo `href` utilizando a função [setAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp).

Veja o exemplo:

```js
var $meuLink = document.getElementById('meuLInk');
var minhaUrl = 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com/';
$meuLink.setAttribute('href', minhaUrl);
```

```html
<a id="meuLInk">Link</a>
```

Comment: A url não é fixa, estou tentando adaptar esse teu codigo para pegar o value do input quando ele é armazenado.

Comment: Basta atribuir o valor no seu código, no momento que você recupera via AJAX.

Comment: Editei a pergunta exibindo o Ajax, pois não entendi como poderia alterar ele. Obrigado pela ajuda.